# How do I use Linq to find the elements of a list that are not present in another list?

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable, subset

I have 2 `List` of `String` variables:

```
List<string> stringList1
List<string> stringList2
```

where `stringList2` is a subset of `stringList1`

now I want all the elements on `stringList1` that aren't in `stringList2`

How do I achieve this using Linq?

Comment: If you're doing this frequently with many items, consider using sets - instant big Oh improvement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to use the `Except` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`

```
var results = stringList1.Except(stringList2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this LINQ expression:

```
from string x in stringList1 where !stringList2.Contains(x) select x;
```

I'm sure there's a built in method, but that's the LINQ. (I don't have VC# with me right now...)